# change TextBox readonly by clicking on ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, event-handling

I have a `TextBox` inside a `ListBoxItem` which is disabled so I can drag and drop it in the `ListBox`.

Once I double click it I want it to be `Enabled` so I can edit the `Text` and when I'm done I want it do be `Disabled` again to do drag and drop.

I have the `MouseDoubleClick` event on the `ListBoxItem` but it doesn't change the `TextBox ReadOnly`. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this.

at the moment `TextBox` returns null. seems like I don't get access to it the way I'm trying.

XAML

```
<ListBox Name="Locations"  Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="351" Margin="10,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
     dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Name="textBox" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="270" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="2"/>
                </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In View

```
private void ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     ListBoxItem item = sender as ListBoxItem;
     textBox.IsReadOnly = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the textbox "doesn't exists" in the visual tree, WPF creates one for each listitem when needed, so you never have a reference to it. It is possible to navigate the visual tree and get the textbox reference but I advise against it, instead, create a property in your item model, something like "EditMode" that when you set it to true, the textbox will enable through the binding of the IsEnabled property.